# Не могу выдать права на ХП в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хочу в PostgreSQL выдать права пользователю на Хранимую процедуру,но оно срабатывает, а права не дает

```
GRANT execute  ON function sch.show(integer,date,date) to role1
```

Вызвать ее нельзя с данной роли

UPD: решил проблему. Оказывается в ХП нужно писать еще `security definer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Оказывается в ХП нужно писать еще security definer

`grant execute` даёт право вызывать функцию. При том, это право изначально есть у [**всех**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html).

> Another point to keep in mind is that by default, execute privilege is granted to PUBLIC for newly created functions

Поэтому, пока вы не сделали самостоятельно `revoke execute ... from public` - делать `grant execute` не особо полезно и ожидаемо ничего не меняет.

При том, право на выполнение функции для всех не является уязвимостью, потому что функции по-умолчанию создаются с `security invoker` - что бы функция не делала, права для этого действия проверяются для того, кто эту функцию вызвал. Например, если функция выполняет чтение таблицы, на которую у вызвавшего функцию пользователя нет прав чтения - получите ошибку доступа.

Вы не указали никаких деталей что у вас происходит, но раз вам "помогло" использование security definer - значит у вас проблема как раз с правами на объекты, которые затрагивает функция, а не с правами на функцию.

Функция созданная с отметкой `security definer` же в свою очередь для всех действий внутри функции проверяет права не для имени вызвавшего функцию пользователя, а для того пользователя, кому эта функция принадлежит. Что используется для, например, предоставления пользователю только набора функций для работы, но без прав обращаться к таблицам и прочим объектам, с которыми работают эти функции. Но помните, что если вы не делаете `revoke` сами - то эту функцию может вызывать кто угодно кто может подключиться к этой базе.